# memory representation in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

Given a pair I want to make a list that contains pair elements and cons of their position in the list(reverse order). Examples:

```
(cons "a" "b") turns into ((0 . 1) "b" "a")
(cons (cons "a" "b") (cons "x" "y")) turns into
((2 . 5) (3 . 4) "y" "x" (0 . 1) "b" "a")
(cons (cons (cons "x" "y") (cons "a" "b")) (cons (cons "x1" "y1") (cons "a1" "b1"))) 
turns into
((6 . 13) (9 . 12) (10 . 11) "b1" "a1" (7 . 8) "y1" "x1" (2 . 5) (3 . 4) "b" "a" (0 . 1) "y" "x")
```

I have no idea how to create the number pairs - don't know what order they follow.

Comment: Wow! That's goofy. Okay, I understand the problem. However... I'm wondering if *you* do. Specifically, you write "don't know what order they follow." Can you expand on whether you're asking a question about what the program is supposed to do or a question about how to write scheme code to do it?

Comment: I would be happy if you could do either of that. For the specific question - I understand why the numbers in the pairs are so but how do I construct them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm definitely assuming this is homework; it would be somewhat crazy to write this function otherwise.  It looks like you're being asked to "flatten" a tree structure into a vector, where each cell contains either a string or a pair. The "counting from the end of the list" is a way of allowing you to model a vector with increasing memory locations; when you add things to the front of the list, the distance from an existing element to the end doesn't change.

With that said, let's get started. This problem is quite complicated, because it uses an accumulator. Actually, it uses two accumulators. The HtDP 2e textbook covers this in section 6:

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_six.html

There is a *lot* of reading that comes before this, and there's a reason for that; it takes a lot of experience to be able to determine what kind of accumulator makes sense for a given problem. In this case, you need to figure out what the "in-between" information is that you need to keep track of as you're in the middle of computing this thing. So, for instance, suppose you're given the tree '(("a" . "b") . "c). Construct the answer by hand, a step at a time. Keep track of the separate steps. See if you can describe what "in-between" information you need to keep track of.

Sigh... this is the kind of problem that instructors assign without thinking about the kind of reasoning required.